# “Guess the Number between 1-1000 game” in C. How can it be made to replay without manually running the program again?

Tags: c

So I have my first C program where you guess the number between 1 and 1000.  It plays well enough, but when I press Y or N to have the user replay the game after winning, it just ends the program.   I want n to kill the program, y to restart it all over again.   How do I accomplish this?   Here's the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

    int random_num = 0;
    int guessed_num = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    char selection = 'y';
    srand(time(NULL));
    random_num = rand() % 1000 + 1;

    printf("I have a number between 1 and 1000, can you guess my number??? ");

    while (selection == 'y')
    {
        counter++;

        scanf_s("%d", &guessed_num);

        if (guessed_num == random_num)
        {
            printf("You guessed correctly in %d tries! Congratulations! Guess again? (y or n)\n", counter);
            scanf_s("%d", &selection);
            break;
        }

        if (guessed_num < random_num)
            printf("Your guess is too low. Guess again. ");

        if (guessed_num > random_num)
            printf("Your guess is too high. Guess again. ");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you look inside [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)? Did you compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`? Did you use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)? Did you read a good C programming book (maybe [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)...), and the documentation of your C compiler and of your debugger?

Answer (score 2):

Your program is waiting for input from user here :

```
if (guessed_num == random_num)
    {
        printf("You guessed correctly in %d tries! Congratulations! Guess again? (y or n)\n", counter);
        scanf_s("%d", &selection);
        break;
    }
```

Even if user selects 'yes' or 'no' , as per your logic , you use the 'break' statement.
This breaks your infinite game loop and you come out even after entering a 'y'.
So, use the solution as told in the previous answer. Hope this clears your doubt

Answer (score 1):

Put your "plays the game once" logic in a larger loop, that after playing the game, asks "do you want to play again?".

```
char play_again = 'y';

while ( play_again == 'y' ) {
   ...
   printf("do you want to play again?");
   scanf_s("%c", &play_again);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're unconditionally calling `break` after you ask the user if they want to play again.  No matter what they choose, `break` will break out of the `while` loop, exiting your program.  Simply get rid of the `break`.  You can also change to `else if` ... `else` conditions since each check is mutually exclusive; no sense in checking for `<` or `>` if we know `==` is true, for instance.

```
if (guessed_num == random_num)
{
  printf("You guessed correctly in %d tries! Congratulations! Guess again? (y or n)\n", counter);
  scanf_s("%d", &selection);
}
else if (guessed_num < random_num)
{
  printf("Your guess is too low. Guess again. ");
}
else
{
  printf("Your guess is too high. Guess again. ");
}
```